# Is this a valid proof of continuity of arcsin at 0?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I came up with simingly simple proof that $\arcsin$ is continuous at $0$, but it seems to me that there is something wrong about it. I assume that I know that $\arcsin$ is an increasing function with domain of $[-1,1]$ and range of $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and that $\sin$ is its inverse function, which also is increasing.
Now the proof itself is the following. Let $\varepsilon$ be any positive real number. Then we will take $\delta=\sin(\min(1,\varepsilon))$. If $-\delta<x<\delta$ then $-\sin(\min(1,\varepsilon))<x<\sin(\min(1,\varepsilon))$. Because $\arcsin$ is increasing and $\sin(\min(1,\varepsilon))$ is in the domain of $\arcsin$ we can say that $\arcsin(-\sin(\min(1,\varepsilon)))<\arcsin(x)<\arcsin(\sin(\min(1,\varepsilon)))$, from which it follos that $-\min(1,\varepsilon)<\arcsin(x)<\min(1,\varepsilon)$. Which means that $-\varepsilon<\arcsin(x)<\varepsilon$. End of the proof.

So my question is, is this proof valid ? I have concerns about it because it seems that in similar way we can prove that any strictly increasing function with domain and range which are closed intervals is continuous(but actually I can't think of any counterexamples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is correct because a bijective and increasing function *is* continuous, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1918170/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you, for clearing this out for me