# Do these functional equations imply linearity?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, symmetry

$f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a strictly decreasing function (i.e. $f(x+\delta)<f(x)\;\forall\;x \in[0,1), \delta>0$), such that $f^{-1}=f$. Further, $f(x)+f(1-x)=1\;\forall\;x\in[0,1]$.

Edit: I earlier said "There is no requirement of continuity". However, while there is no explicit continuity requirement, I think these properties imply continuity as pointed out in the comments.

Does this imply $f$ must be linear?

My approach: I drew the pictures. Due to $f^{-1}=f$, $f$ must look the same when we rotate the page by $90^{o}$ so that the y-axis becomes the x-axis. By strict decreasingness, it must be strictly above $1/2$ for $x<1/2$, equal to $1/2$ for $x=1/2$ (by $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$) and strictly below $1/2$ for $x>1/2$. In addition, due to $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$, when you reflect it around the $y=1/2$ line and then the $x=1/2$ line, you get back the same function. To me it seems this means $f$ in $[1/2,1]$ is a replica of $f$ in $[0,1/2]$ except "dragged down", I *think* by $1/2$ but I'm not sure. i.e. $f(x)=f(x-1/2)-1/2$ for $x>1/2$, but I'm not sure.

To me it seems  the replica property combined with the rotational symmetry property described above, indicates that this can't hold unless $f$ is linear.

Obviously, the above is vague, and I'm not even sure it goes loosely in the right direction. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: There is no continuity requirement? I think it is hidden.

Comment: Well it doesn't say that $f$ has to be continuous. But now that I think about it, if $f$ has jump discontinuities, $f^{-1}$ will have flat regions in those places, which violates strict decreasingness, so I think you're right... continuity is implied by these properties. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: A [a bijective, strictly increasing function is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918145/prove-that-a-bijective-strictly-increasing-function-is-continuous) indeed.

Comment: Doesn't strictly increasing imply bijective?

Comment: Thank you so much for the link btw

Comment: @Canine360 *Doesn't strictly increasing mean bijective?* For sure not!!! $f(x) = x/3$ on $[0, 1/2)$ and $f(x)= x $ on $[1/2,1]$ is strictly increasing but not continuous.

Comment: But this function (Your example) does have an inverse - $f(x)=3x$ for $x\leq 1/6$, $f(x)=1/2$ for $1/6<x\leq 1/2, f(x)=x$ otherwise. So in my question bijectivity is implied by what? Is it the fact that $f^{-1}=f$? Thanks!

Comment: @Canine360 My example doesn't have an inverse. For example, $1/3$ doesn't have an inverse image under $f$. $f(x)=1/2$ for $1/6 \lt x \le 1/2$ can't be bijective... all an interval is mapped to $1/2$!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $f$ is strictly decreasing from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$. As it is supposed to be bijective, $f(0)= 1$ and $f(1)=0$. *$f$ is also continuous, but we don't need this in what follows.*

Let's prove that $f(x) = 1-x$ if we suppose in addition that $f(x) + f(1-x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and $f=f^{-1}$.

Suppose that it exists $a \in (0,1)$ such that $f(a) \lt 1-a$. Then

$$a = f^{-1}(f(a)) \gt f^{-1}(1-a) = f(1-a) = 1 - f(a)$$ and therefore $a + f(a) \gt 1$. A contradiction with the hypothesis $f(a) \lt 1-a$.

We'll get a similar contradiction if we suppose that it exists $a \in (0,1)$ such that $f(a) \gt 1-a$.

**Conclusion: the only option is $f(x) = 1-x$, which is indeed linear.**

Comment: Clear and simple answer.

Comment: Thank  you so much! As I said earlier, I'm confused about bijectivity. :( 2 ques. (1) Is bijectivity a result of $f^{-1}=f$? (2) If I understand correctly this should remain valid if we replace $[0,1]$ with any $[b,1-b], b \in (0,1/2)$ as well, right?

Comment: (a) By definition, and I suggest you have a look again at this definition, you can’t even speak of $f^{-1}$ if $f$ is not bijective. By the way looking again and again at definitions, is not loosing time in mathematics. (b) That is correct.